# Is it possible to declare multiple micrometer binders in a single bean declaration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

> By default, metrics from all `MeterBinder` beans will be automatically bound to the Spring-managed `MeterRegistry`

This works great when it's possible to configure the binders individually. What I'm looking, however, it to be able to bulk declare multiple binders. My use case is based on programmatically declaring and creating multiple rabbit queues. The `spring-amqp` project comes handy with a concept of `Declarables` class which is:

> A collection of `Declarable` objects; used to declare multiple objects on the broker using a single bean declaration for the collection.

Is there a simlar concept present in spring-boot, I'd call it `MeterBinders` which allows me to declate multiple meter objects, using a single bean declaration.

I'd like to avoid simultanious declatarion of my queues and meters (with `new QueueSizeMeterBinder(queueInformation).bindTo(meterRegistry)` - keep these separate).

Currently, to keep these concepts separated, I'm using additional configuration class, which doesn't look to me as an idiomatic spring-way

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class QueueMetricsConfiguration {

    private final Declarables queues;
    private final AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;
    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void bindMetrics() {
        queues.getDeclarablesByType(Queue.class)
                .forEach(queue -> new QueueSizeMeterBinder(amqpAdmin.getQueueInfo(queue.getName()))
                        .bindTo(meterRegistry));
    }

}
```

Can I do it any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get your explanation right, but registering multiple bindings in one `MeterBinder` would be something I have called a composite-binder in my projects:

```
@Bean
MeterBinder compositeBinder() {
    return (registry) -> {
        // register Meters via a binder
        new FooBinder().bindTo(registry);
        new BarBinder().bindTo(registry);
        // register without indirection
        registry.gauge("mygauge", BigDecimal.TEN);
    };
}
```